# In plotly express, how can I rename the axes and the name of my legend? The y-axis is only showing as values and the title on the legend is variable

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

My code:

#The line plot of successful launches color coded by the launchpad

```
launch_sum = pd.get_dummies(spacex_df,columns=["launchpad"])[["year","launchpad_CCSFS SLC 40","launchpad_KSC LC 39A","launchpad_VAFB SLC 4E","launch_success_True","launch_success_False"]]
launch_sum.rename(columns={"launchpad_CCSFS SLC 40":"CCSFS SLC 40","launchpad_KSC LC 39A":"KSC LC 39A","launchpad_VAFB SLC 4E":"VAFB SLC 4E"},inplace=True)
launch_sum = launch_sum.groupby("year").sum()

px.line(launch_sum, y=["CCSFS SLC 40","KSC LC 39A","VAFB SLC 4E"],title="The Total Annual Attempted Launches")
```

The output is the plot but I cannot change the ylabel and the title of the legend.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/feBYt.png

Answer (score 5):

Simple case of updating appropriate titles in layout

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

launch_sum = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        c: np.random.randint(1, 8, 8)
        for c in ["CCSFS SLC 40", "KSC LC 39A", "VAFB SLC 4E"]
    },
    index=range(2018, 2018 + 8),
)

px.line(
    launch_sum,
    y=["CCSFS SLC 40", "KSC LC 39A", "VAFB SLC 4E"],
    title="The Total Annual Attempted Launches",
).update_layout(yaxis={"title": "some text"}, legend={"title":"column"})
```

Comment: thank  you! This worked perfectly :)

Comment: I cannot upvote your answer cause I don't have enough reputation. I am sorry, I am new to programming and my account is very new.